# How to Replace Webpage Not Available Page To Custom Page? (WEBVIEW)

Tags: javascript, android, html, kotlin, webview

I want to change page from `Webpage not Available` or `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

to **My Page "No Internet Connection"**?

and with a refresh button to back online if online or connected internet again, and if didn't connect just stay in Page **No Internet Connection**.

Look like a page `HTML` not default notif page `android`.

I'm using a `Android Studio` with `Kotlin`

This is `MyActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    internal var webView: WebView? = null
    private var mCM: String? = null
    private var mUM: ValueCallback<Uri>? = null
    private var mUMA: ValueCallback<Array<Uri?>>? = null

    //select whether you want to upload multiple files (set 'true' for yes)
    private val multiple_files = false

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView = findViewById(R.id.ifView) as WebView
        assert(webView != null)
        val webSettings = webView!!.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings.allowFileAccess = true

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webSettings.mixedContentMode = 0
            webView!!.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        }
        else {
            webView!!.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
        }
        webView!!.webViewClient = Callback()
        webView!!.loadUrl("http://xxx.xxx.xxx") //add your test web/page address here
        webView!!.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient()
}
```

This is my code `Callback`

```
inner class Callback : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, errorCode: Int, description: String, failingUrl: String) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }
```

For sure, my apps want load offline page where `webview` offline to notif the apps didn't connect internet, and connect again to the internet showing online page when `webview` online

Comment: can i see the code in `Callback` webview?

Comment: wait a momment i'll edit my quest

Comment: okay wait for me..

Answer (score 1):

Replace default WebChromeClient with your custom CustomWebviewClient as below

```
webView!!.setWebViewClient(object : CustomWebviewClient()
```

then create this custom WebViewClient

```
    inner class CustomWebviewClient : WebViewClient() {

    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    }

    override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)

        if (noInternetConnection()) {
            loadNoInternetErrorView()
        } else {
            loadErrorMessageView()
        }
    }
}
```

whenever your WebView fails to load page it calls `onReceivedError` callback there you can show error layout. For error view you can create error layout within your layout with initial visiblity View.GONE and make it visible when error occurrs.

Changes to your **XML** file

```
<WebView 
   android:id="@+id/webView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/error_screen"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <Textview 
    android:id="@+id/error_msg" />
  ................
  <ImageView
    android:id=:"@+id/error_icon/>
  //error view


</LinearLayout>
```

In **loadErrorMessageView** you can do this

```
loadErrorMessageView() {
 webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 error_screen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 error_msg.setText("Some error Occurred");
}
```

Similarly you can do for NoInternet case maybe you can show "No internet message" than "Some error occurred" I hope this clears your doubt

Comment: and where to include the code or call the custom page HTML to view my layout custom error. And a layout must a layout android or page HTML(in folder asset)?

Comment: layout i meant you'll have a fullscreen webview right. Alongside that webview create a full screen error page in XML layout with initial visibility gone and webview visible but when error occurs change webview visibility to gone and error to visible.

Comment: yess, but to call the "error page" i must call code in where in your code? becuase im newbie in android and try to learn :D

Comment: I think to call the page in here "loadErrorMessageView("http://xx.xx.xx/errorpage.html") ?

Comment: Is like this?
"loadErrorMessageView("xx.xx.xx/errorpage.html")" I'm input the page HTML in "()" loadErrorMessageView ?

Comment: And for the code "loadNoInternetErrorView()" to call layout or somethings?

Comment: I have updated answer see it you understand better now

Comment: Okay, i will try sirrrrrr. Thanks for respon to me hehe :D

Comment: If you still face any problem let me know i'll provide complete working solution if given time.

Comment: Roger that!!, i will try this tomorrow sir :D

Comment: And after use this code. My code use FileChooser. And error showing up in
'override fun onShowFileChooser' with comment error "onShowFileChooser overrides nothing"

Comment: I made a mistake rather than setWebchromeClient please use setWebViewClient. Also sharing a link for this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/.

Comment: When i'm used setWebViewClient the red error come to many errors. and CustomWebviewClient still red error with comment error "Unresolved reference : CustomWebviewClient" :(